# How to create an SD Card image file for the Android emulator?

Tags: android, image, file, emulation, sd-card

I need to create an SD Card image file for an Android emulator that I am running. Given that I am a beginner at Android development, a complete step-by-step tutorial would be awesome.

Comment: Please include information on the various techniques/options you have already tried.

Answer (score 14):

There is a command line program for doing that called mksdcard:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/mksdcard.html

Answer (score 7):

There are already SD Card image files for use with the emulator installed.

If you create an AVD then choose a file path for the SD Card

on My Machine the file path is:

```
C:\Users\Samir\.android\avd\Android2.2.avd\sdcard
```

Then, click 'Ok' and save the changes, then this will emulate an SD Card when you run the use the AVD in the Emulator

Comment: What's the path in mac ?

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone please tell me how to do that.

In the AVD Manager, when you create an AVD, fill in a positive integer in the "SD Card" field. This is the size of your SD card in MB.

Comment: The OP was asking how he can create the SD card image file. This is not the same as what you're suggesting.

Comment: @MichellBak: First, if the OP is a beginner, as noted, I feel reasonably confident that I have interpreted the question correctly, and that the OP simply wants external storage. Second, my answer is correct, regardless, because filling in a value there creates an SD card image, stored in the `.android` subdirectory associated with the AVD file (e.g., `.android/avd/name-of-your.avd/sdcard.img`).

Comment: I guess there are two ways to look at this. You can manually use the mksdcard program from cmd or you can use the option in the AVD setup to create one in the default path, and then use this file with other AVD's as well. I personally find it easier to have the SD card images in one place rather than in the default path - it makes it easier if you're using the same file for multiple AVD's.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Wge]

When you create a virtual device there is an Option for SD Card :
You can select a file where you want ur SD card, or you can also give size for SD card, so that it will create and SD card image for you on the default android emulator location.

Answer (score 0):

You can Google search before and find this: http://www.androiddevelopment.org/2008/11/11/how-to-create-and-use-the-sd-card-with-the-android-emulator/