# How to handle this SD card Android emulator error?

Tags: android, emulation

I wanted to add a file to the sd card of the android emulator but i receive this error:

Failed to push selection: Read-only file system

What shall I do? I am an Android beginner and still learning how to use the terminal and all that stuff. So please, can someone give me a step-by-step tutorial and not just another link?

Comment: 1. be sure to create a sdcard like file. 2. be sure to push into the /sdcard directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an SD Card image file for the Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754195/how-to-create-an-sd-card-image-file-for-the-android-emulator), amongst others.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.streamhead.com/android-tutorial-sd-card/) is a tutorial regarding creation of SD Card. While creating the current SD card, you may not have given it write permission. Follow the steps in that tutorial and you will be able to upload image to SD card.

***EDIT***

Step1: `...tools>android create avd -n myemulator -t 8`

Step2: `...tools>mksdcard -l e 512M mysdcard.img`

Step3: `...tools>emulator -avd myemulator -sdcard mysdcard`

Comment: Thank you! One more question: can you explain me step one of that tutorial a little more? How do I send that command? Via terminal? What do I have to type in?

Comment: search for "mksdcard"  in your PC and on the command prompt give that path and start off

Comment: When I open up mksdcard it says [Process completed]. But in the end nothing happened..

Comment: you are using windows or linux?

Comment: ok... in terminal, navigate to the folder containing "mksdcard" and then perform the steps given in the tutorial

Comment: so that would be: cd /Users/MY_USERNAME/Developer/android-sdk-macosx/tools/

Comment: right! and now write: `mksdcard -l mysdcard 128M sdcard.img` to make SD card of 128 MB

Comment: i did exactly that and NOTHING happened! what now??

Comment: check the EDIT part. This worked for me. This will create a whole new AVD. Let me know if it works. See you on monday.

Comment: hey, and what shall I do with your edit? type into terminal??

Comment: @user1413437, you had to write it in the terminal itself! thought the `tools>` would give you a hint to write it in terminal!!!